# How to grab regex matches in RapidMiner?

Tags: regex, tokenize, rapidminer

I tried to use `Tokenize` to search for IP addresses with port number

[image]

but apparently it uses regexp to define token delimiter, i.e. it returns text BETWEEN ip addresses. Is it possible to retrieve addresses themselves?

**UPDATE**

I have one big textual log file as input. It has rows, rows contain some messages about IP addresses. I would like to take all addresses an group them counting.

Is it possible with RapidMiner?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the example set to contain attributes with names equal to the IP address and optional port you could try the following.

Pass the documents to the `Process Documents` operator.

Inside this use `Tokenize` with the following regular expression.

`[^0-9.:]`

Immediately after this, use the `Filter Token (by Content)` operator with the condition `contains match` and the following regular expression.

`\d+\.{1}\d+\.{1}\d+\.{1}\d+:*\d*`

Comment: I have one file. Is it "document"? Please explain how can your method work?

Comment: In the `Process Documents` operator, set the `Vector Creation` parameter to be `Term Occurrences`. This will count the number of times the attribute appears in the single document.

Comment: For information there is the `Keep Document Parts` operator that allows content of interest to be kept prior to tokenizing.